Clang-tidy tries to analyze an STM32 assembly file located in compile_commands.json
I have an STM32 project which is compiled using CMake and generates a compile_commands.json
STM32CubeMX generates an assembly file (i.e. startup_stm32f103xb.s) and adds it to the compilation database.
Whenever I run use-clang-tidy.py, it attempts to analyse that file and returns an error:
D:\git\leany\Core\startup_stm32f103xb.s:28:3: error: expected identifier or '(' [clang-diagnostic-error]
   28 |   .syntax unified
      |   ^

I'm not surprised by the error as clang tries to compile an ASM file as C, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to just ignore this file or any asm file altogether.
Also, I would very much like to keep clang-tidy as a part of my CI/CD procedures, as I want to keep my own code (located in Components/) as clean as possible.
Also, I cannot touch the files generated by STM32CubeMX, neither can I touch the CMake files it creates.
Here is the codebase : Github
I've tried to create a .clang-tidy file at the root of the project with the mention 'Checks: "-*"', but it just cancels all checks altogether, including the ones located in Components/
I've also tried adding HeaderFileExtensions and ImplementationFileExtensions sections in it to consider only *.h and *.c files, but this doesn't change anything

I've found the solution on the LLVM forum !
From the help, I did not understand that [files ...] expected a regex.
I've just added files ".*(?<!\.s)$" at the end of the command to filter out the assembly file

According to the doc if you run
clang-tidy --dump-config

you will get a list of supported config options:
---
Checks:              '-*,some-check'
WarningsAsErrors:    ''
HeaderFileExtensions:         ['', 'h','hh','hpp','hxx']
ImplementationFileExtensions: ['c','cc','cpp','cxx']
HeaderFilterRegex:   ''
FormatStyle:         none
InheritParentConfig: true
User:                user
CheckOptions:
some-check.SomeOption: 'some value'

It looks like these options may work:
HeaderFileExtensions:         ['', 'h','hh','hpp','hxx']
ImplementationFileExtensions: ['c','cc','cpp','cxx']


I've tried creating a .clang-tidy file at the root of the project with this and it returns the following message :

Error parsing D:/git/leany.clang-tidy: invalid argument
D:/git/leany/cmake/stm32cubemx/../...clang-tidy:5:1: error: unknown key 'ExcludeRegex'
ExcludeRegex: '.*.(s|S|asm)$'
^~~~~~~~~~~~
This might be a deprecated clang-tidy argument of some sort :/
If so, it's a pity, though, as it would have been a pretty clean option


I've changed the root .clang-tidy file with HeaderFileExtensions and ImplementationFileExtensions to take only *.h and *.c into account, but the outcome is the same. --dump-config shows only those now
